# Subsetting rows based on multiple columns using data.table - fastest way

Tags: r

I was wondering if there was a more elegant, less clunky and faster way to do this. I have millions of rows with ICD coding for clinical data. A short example provided below. I was to subset the dataset based on either of the columns meeting a specific set of diagnosis codes. The code below works but takes ages in R and was wondering if there is a faster way.

```
structure(list(eid = 1:10, mc1 = structure(c(4L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("345", "410", "413.9", "I20.1", 
"I23.4"), class = "factor"), oc1 = c(350, 323, 12, 35, 413.1, 
345, 345, 345, 345, 345), oc2 = structure(c(5L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("", "345", "I20.3", "J23.6", 
"K50.1", "K51.4"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("eid", "mc1", 
"oc1", "oc2"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x102812578>)
```

The code below subsets all rows that meet the code of either "I20" or "413" (this would include all codes that have for example been coded as "I20.4" or "413.9" etc.

```
dat2 <- dat [substr(dat$mc1,1,3)== "413"|
           substr(dat$oc1,1,3)== "413"|
           substr(dat$oc2,1,3)== "413"|
           substr(dat$mc1,1,3)== "I20"|
           substr(dat$oc1,1,3)== "I20"|
           substr(dat$oc2,1,3)== "I20"]
```

Is there a faster way to do this? For example can i loop through each of the columns looking for the specific codes "I20"  or "413" and subset those rows?

Comment: Are you aware of https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/icd/index.html ?

Comment: The problem is that your columns is not in character format, if you transform them to characters bewforehand (or specify the format when reading the data) then `substr` will be much faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can specify the columns of interest in `.SDcols`, loop through the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`), get the first 3 characters with `substr`, check whether it is `%in%` a `vector` of values and `Reduce` it to a single logical `vector` for subsetting the rows

```
dat[dat[,Reduce(`|`, lapply(.SD, function(x)
            substr(x, 1, 3) %chin% c('413', 'I20'))), .SDcols = 2:4]]
#   eid   mc1   oc1   oc2
#1:   1 I20.1 350.0 K50.1
#2:   2 413.9 323.0 K51.4
#3:   5   345 413.1      
#4:   9   345 345.0 I20.3
```

Answer (score 0):

For larger data it could help if we dont chech all rows:

```
minem <- function(dt, colsID = 2:4) {
  cols <- colnames(dt)[colsID]
  x <- c('413', 'I20')
  set(dt, j = "inn", value = F)
  for (i in cols) {
    dt[inn == F, inn := substr(get(i), 1, 3) %chin% x]
  }
  dt[inn == T][, inn := NULL][]
}

n <- 1e7
set.seed(13)
dt <- dts[sample(.N, n, replace = T)]
dt <- cbind(dt, dts[sample(.N, n, replace = T), 2:4])
setnames(dt, make.names(colnames(dt), unique = T))
dt
#           eid   mc1   oc1   oc2 mc1.1 oc1.1 oc2.1
#        1:   8   345 345.0   345   345   345   345
#        2:   3 I23.4  12.0 J23.6 413.9   323 K51.4
#        3:   4   410  35.0       413.9   323 K51.4
#        4:   1 I20.1 350.0 K50.1 I23.4    12 J23.6
#        5:  10   345 345.0   345   345   345   345
#      ---                                        
#  9999996:   3 I23.4  12.0 J23.6 I20.1   350 K50.1
#  9999997:   5   345 413.1       I20.1   350 K50.1
#  9999998:   4   410  35.0         345   345   345
#  9999999:   4   410  35.0         410    35      
# 10000000:  10   345 345.0   345   345   345 I20.3

system.time(r1 <- akrun(dt, 2:ncol(dt))) # 22.88 sek
system.time(r2 <- minem(dt, 2:ncol(dt))) # 17.72 sek
all.equal(r1, r2)
# [1] TRUE
```